# Which one is the 4G sim slot in Redmi 3s prime?

Tags: 4g, xiaomi

I have acquired an Jio sim and I am using a Redmi 3s prime. But I don’t know which one is the primary 4G sim slot in the phone. Is it the nano one or the micro one? Or can i choose any one of them? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Redmi 3S Prime** uses a **hybrid SIM slot** which means it accepts *one Micro-SIM* and *another Nano-SIM or microSD card for storage*.

Unfortunately, this means that users will have to choose between a second SIM and a microSD card.

***Coming to your question*** : Use any slot for 4G. It is recommended from my side, use the micro-sim slot for the primary sim.

Answer (score 0):

The Redmi 3S Prime supports hybrid dual-SIM (Micro-SIM + Nano-SIM) slot with the second SIM slot also capable of functioning as a microSD slot. However either slot can be used for 4G.